# What exactly means equal '=' in PHP and how can I deduce where is a simply assign or array extend?

Tags: php

I just discovered that '=' sign behave differently for arrays in php and I can't find a good explanation for that. I considered PHP the most powerful and elegant language (even interpreted) that at least, follows a simple and straight forward syntax, using curly brackets (eg. not indents) or start numbering array elements from 0 (eg. not from 1 like in vb).

```
<?php

$errors = array();

$errors[] = "first element";
$errors[] = "2'nd element";
$errors[] = "3'rd element";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($errors);
echo "</pre>";


?>
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => first element
    [1] => 2'nd element
    [2] => 3'rd element
)
```

Which is quite odd to me (C,C#,etc..). 
The '=' Isn't suppose to re-initialize the object?

I have no problem with this, but isn't it quite confusing?
What is the logic behind and how can I deduce where '=' means equal or assign and not extend object and create a new element in it?

Comment: So what exactly did you expect `$errors[] =` to do?

Comment: wow.. looks like I'll definitely gain some -100 votes, but I am just curios for a reasonable answer, not some downvotes that means nothing.

Comment: `=` always means *assign*; the only confusion you have is what assignment to `$arr[]` means.

Comment: What's your actual question?  Why a particular language has a particular feature?  That seems like something you'd ask whoever designed the language.  If you're just complaining that you don't like this syntax, Stack Overflow is not your soapbox.

Comment: @David, no I clearly don't mean that. Just asking how to use it properly.

Comment: you can do array_push($errors,"first element","second element ","...") if you want some standard way :0

Comment: @user1797147: The code in the question seems to already use that syntax properly.  There's no error or unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is always an assignment, the only special case here is the assignment to `$arr[]`. You may read that as *"assignment to unspecified array key"*, and it results in the array key being auto-generated. It's analogous to `arr.push(...)` or similar in many other languages.

Comment: Ok, so only for $arr[] means automatically extending that array and inserting a new element. Curious, but clear enough. I was expecting dropping all elements (like obj = new obj) and create only one element. If I wanted to insert, use some insert method.

Answer (score 1):

`=` means "assign". What's different between `$errors = "first element";` and `$errors[] = "first element";` is what you're assigning to....

```
$errors = "first element";
```

assigns the value to a variable called `$errors`

```
$errors = array();
$errors[] = "first element";
```

assigns the value to the next element in an "array variable" called `$errors`

---

However, there is no "addition" anywhere here. Addition is a mathematical operation that sums numbers together.... be vary careful using the term in the context of creating a new array element

Comment: Right, I was talking about inserting a new element. Apologize.